# How to access a div element inside a iframe in a different domain using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I want to access a div element inside a iframe. This iframe load from a different domain.

below code I tried:

```
$('iframe').contents().find(".questions").width()
```

Comment: As long as [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is not enabled for both domains you cannot.

Comment: What do you expect with width()? Can you try hide() or something similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: @empiric I have loaded this iframe in vue frontend and load jquery based domain into  this iframe.When I used above code I could not able to take the width of the element.

Comment: @kmgt No. I want to get width of this div to calculation. Any way I want to get element width only

Answer (score 0):

Are there multiple `.questions` class?

To get witdth of first one, try this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find(".questions:first").width();
```

Comment: If this works, then you have to loop through this line to get all `.questions` divisions' width.